# Javascript placement bug

Tags: javascript

At http://www.langThis.com we have tried making a button to translate peoples home pages.
But a ever returning problem is our Javascript for the popup. It should show the popup around the "langthis button" as shown on www.langthis.com, but as seen on this page I found it sometimes shows up where it want: www.giftsconcept.net/svp/ (in the bottom of the page).

Anyone who can help in bug fixing this problem?

Ex. of our JS code: http://www.langthis.com/langthisjs.php?site=1&user=langthis&from=gb

Answer (score 0):

You don't calculate the viewports position of the popup! If someone scrolls down the page the popup is "mispositioned".